# Ajax is not defined

Tags: ajax, wp-enqueue-script, wp-localize-script

Stack Exchange long time listener, first time caller.

I have found examples on the developer.wordpress site but I have been still struggling.

Localizing scripts:
[wp_localize_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/#comment-content-1391)

In my theme's functions.php file, I have:

```
function wp_my_ajax_script() {
   wp_localize_script( 'ajax_handle_agent_search', 'myAjax', admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ));        

   wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax_handle_agent_search' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_my_ajax_script' );
```

And on my page, I've added a HTML code wdiget that contains:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    console.log("Document loaded");
   jQuery("#searchButton").click( function(e) {
      console.log("Search button clicked");
      console.log("Ajax: " . myAjax);
      e.preventDefault(); 
      var zipCode = document.getElementById("inputField").value;
      console.log("Zip code entered: " + zipCode);
      jQuery.ajax({
         type : "post",
         dataType : "json",
         url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
         data : {
             action: "zip_search_action",
             zip_code : zipCode
         },
         success: function(response) {
            if(response.type == "success") {
                console.log("In success");
                document.getElementById("results").html = response.data;
            }
            else {
                console.log("In success, in else!");
            }
         },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log("In error, error thrown!");
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
      })   

   });

});
</script>

<input type="text" id="inputField">
<input type="button" value="Search" id="searchButton">
```

Then I load the page, enter a zip code in to the input field and click the button.  The developer tools console shows:

[image: Developer Tool console with error message]

I've been working on this for a few weeks now and I've gotten much better at developing for Wordpress, but web dev isn't my forte, so after I feel I've reached my limit, I'm reaching out for help.  Any insight to get me moving forward would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

=================================
EDIT 3/12/20 at 1342 CST

I've moved the JS code to it's own file in the theme's JS directory with the permissions 0755.  Then I've added a new function to my functions.php file with the enqueue and localize function calls (as seen below)

```
function my_load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'zip_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/zip_search.js' );
    wp_localize_script( 'zip_js', 'Zip_JS', null);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_load_scripts');
```

Now the console shows:
[image: jQuery error]

### ================================++++= EDIT 3/13/20 at 0806 CST

I have gotten further.  Atleast I believe so.  Below is the code as it currently is in Wordpress followed by a screenshot of the console error.

In my JS file ():

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    console.log("Document loaded");
   jQuery("#searchButton").click( function(e) {
      console.log("Search button clicked");
      e.preventDefault(); 
      var zipCode = document.getElementById("inputField").value;
      console.log("Zip code entered: " + zipCode);
      jQuery.ajax({
         type : "post",
         dataType : "json",
         url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
         data : {
             action: "zip_search",
             zip_code : zipCode
         },
         success: function(response) {
            if(response.type == "success") {
                console.log("In success");
                //jQuery("#results").html(response.data);
                document.getElementById("results").html = response.data;
            }
            else {
                console.log("In success, in else!");
                console.log(response);
            }
         },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log("In error, error thrown!");
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
      });   
   });

});
```

In functions.php including my DB query this time:

```
function my_load_scripts() {

    // Enqueue javascript on the frontend.
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'zip_js',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/zip_search.js',
        array('jquery')
    );

    // The wp_localize_script allows us to output the ajax_url path for our script to use.
    wp_localize_script(
        'zip_js',
        'myAjax',
        array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) )
    );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_load_scripts' );



function zip_search()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $output = '';

    $zip = $_REQUEST['zipCode'];    

    $query = 'SELECT county FROM Agent WHERE zip = %s';
    $result = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare($query, $zip) );
    $output .= "<p>";
    $output .= $result;
    $output .= "</p>";

    $query = 'SELECT zip, county, zone, agent FROM Agent WHERE county = %s';

    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare($query, $result) ); 


    $output .= "<ul>";
    foreach( $results as $result ) 
    {
        $output .= "<li>".$result->zip." - ".$result->zone." - ".$result->agent."</li>";
    }
    $output .= "</ul>";

    $result['type'] = "success";
    $result['data'] = $output;

    return json_encode($result);
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_zip_search_action', 'zip_search');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_zip_search_action', 'zip_search' );
```

On my Wordpress page:

```
<input type="text" id="inputField">
<input type="button" value="Search" id="searchButton">
```

Console:
[image: New console error with status 200 and statusText of "OK"]

---

### EDIT: 3/13/2020 at 11:52am CST

### Adding working code.  Hopefully anyone that is having close to the same issue can see what I did to make this work and it will help somehow.

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    console.log("Document loaded");
   jQuery("#searchButton").click( function(e) {
      console.log("Search button clicked");
      e.preventDefault(); 
      var zipCode = document.getElementById("inputField").value;
      console.log("Zip code entered: " + zipCode);
      jQuery.ajax({
         type : "post",
         dataType : "json",
         url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
         data : {
             'action': "zip_search",
             'zip_code' : zipCode
         },
         success: function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            if(response.success) {
                console.log("response.type == success");
                jQuery("#results").html(response.data.data);
            }
            else {
                console.log("response.type == else");
                console.log(response.data);
            }
         },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log("In error, error thrown!");
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
      })
   })
})
```

functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_zip_search', 'zip_search');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_zip_search', 'zip_search' );
function zip_search()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $output = '';

    $zip = $_REQUEST["zip_code"];   


    $query = 'SELECT county FROM Agent WHERE zip = %s';
    $result = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare($query, $zip) );
    $output .= "<p>";
    $output .= $result;
    $output .= "</p>";

    $query = 'SELECT zip, county, zone, agent FROM Agent WHERE county = %s';

    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare($query, $result) ); 


    $output .= "<ul>";
    foreach( $results as $result ) 
    {
        $output .= "<li>".$result->zip." - ".$result->zone." - ".$result->agent."</li>";
    }
    $output .= "</ul>";

    $response = array(
        'data' => $output,
    );

    wp_send_json_success($response);

    //return json_encode($response);
    //die();
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_load_scripts' );
function my_load_scripts() {

    // Enqueue javascript on the frontend.
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'zip_js',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/zip_search.js',
        array('jquery')
    );

    // The wp_localize_script allows us to output the ajax_url path for our script to use.
    wp_localize_script(
        'zip_js',
        'myAjax',
        array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) )
    );

}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="inputField" placeholder="Enter zip code here">
<input type="button" value="Search" id="searchButton">
```

Comment: Just curious, but you used the old fashioned Admin AJAX rather than the modern REST API endpoints for your AJAX query, why?

Comment: It is what I found while looking up "how-to" information.  I'm more comforatable with backend coding (OO and SQL), but I was asked to help with a Wordpress site, which is way beyond my capabilities.  To answer that question, I do not know of anything else.

Comment: Can you link us to what you found and tried to follow?

Comment: I have viewed many pages, but here is the most recent page I had been using: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress-a-real-world-example/

Comment: Since this is an inline script and not a traditional enqueue, you cannot use localize_script. The enqueue_script function is meant for external scripts, in their own JS files. Is it possible to move your code into it's own JS file and enqueue it properly?

Comment: as codex says, IMPORTANT! wp_localize_script() MUST be called after the script has been registered using wp_register_script() or wp_enqueue_script().

Comment: Does the ajax load after the inline javascript?  Do I need to enqueue or localize anything if it is inline JS?

Comment: @DanielNebert in your updated code snippet, I see you tell WP that the data you want to localise is `null`, and i see that your code depends on jQuery, but you never tell WP this when you enqueue the script

Comment: @TomJNowell, not too sure what I am doing.  The developer.wordpress states on the wp_localize_script page that the third argument is:

(array) (Required) The data itself. The data can be either a single or multi-dimensional array.

And since I don't know the data I want to use until the user enters a Zip Code in to the input box and clicks send, I wasn't sure which value to localize it with.

On a side note, I wasn't sure why I needed to pull the JS out of the HTML on the page.  The updated snippet and the original code still gave me the same error message.

Comment: I am learning more about how jquery and AJAX works with Wordpress and I plan to come back and answer my question with a solutions.  Thanks all for your time!

Comment: @DanielNebert the data it's talking about is the data you want to give to the script on the frontend when it first loads, your script needed to know where admin-ajax.php was.  `wp_localise_script` is just a way to set some initial data that the script needs from PHP. Did you write this code?

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I am posting the working code as an edit above.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not defined because you've not referred jQuery as dependency for your script so wp isn't aware it should load it for your script.

`wp_localize_script` should be called on script that is already linked via `wp_enqueue_script`, so you first run `wp_enqueue_script` then `wp_localize_script` as you do in your UPD.

Another thing about `wp_localize_script` is it takes 3 arguments (see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/), and last one is associative array.

So if in your JS code you want to get `ajaxurl` via `myAjax.ajaxurl` you need to call `wp_localize_script( 'zip_js', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ));`

Code below takes into account your new naming of script as `zip_js` and global js variable is now `Zip_JS`, so you will access your `ajaxurl` in js code like `Zip_JS.ajaxurl` instead of `myAjax.ajaxurl` .

Here's how you need to do to fix jQuery missing error, and also use localize script properly:

```
function my_load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'zip_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/zip_search.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_localize_script( 'zip_js', 'Zip_JS', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_load_scripts');
```

Comment: Hello!  Yes, I actually did add that part in before learning work yesterday, but didn't work.   This morning, I made a few new changes which did finally see jquery and get past that error.  Now, the response status is 200 and statusText is "OK".  But in JS, it reaches "error: function(errorThrown)".  Allow me a little bit today to work with it and double check all my syntax.

Comment: Yes.  I have now learned how to fix that missing jQuery error.  I'm getting better at Wordpress everyday and I actually think I could keep using this for my own sites.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I am posting the working code as an edit above.

Comment: @DanielNebert one thing to improve `$zip = $_REQUEST['zipCode']; ` should be sanitized like `$zip = sanitize_text_field(  isset($_REQUEST['zipCode']) ? $_REQUEST['zipCode'] : '') ); `

Comment: That is a good heads up.  Thank you.  I was going to start working on making it better, so I'm happy for the info.  I'll make that change and account for the zip code being an empty string and returning the HTML to inform the user accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
        #try this
    function wpb_adding_scripts() {
        wp_register_script('my_amazing_scripts', plugins_url('jquery.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '3.4.1', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('my_amazing_scripts');
    }


        <form id="article_form" name="article_form" class="wordpress-ajax-form" method="post" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="custom_action">
        </form>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(evt) {
  $(".wordpress-ajax-form").submit(function(evt){  

            $.ajax({
                url: $('#article_form').attr('action'),
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                processData: false,
                success: function (response) {
                 alert(response);

                }
              });
    });  
  });
```

Comment: Hi there, I will try this next.  I feel I am so close with the other code that I've been receiving help with above and didn't want to bounce between as to confuse myself or make mistakes.  What does enctype: 'multipart/form-data' do?

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I am posting the working code as an edit above.